# QR code used as a confirmation code

Tags: android, zxing

Good evening,

I'm working on a mobile augmented reality game and I wanted to use QR codes as a part of the game. What I wanted to do was to create QR codes myself which serve the purpose of passkeys in order to be able to proceed to the next stages of the game. So in that sense, I need users to be able to scan a QR code from a location out in the streets and if the QR code is the appropriate one, the application will proceed to the next activity in order to continue with the flow of the game.

I have in general checked the ZXing libraries but could not figure out exactly if I can use QR codes in this manner, so I decided to ask here if anyone has worked on / done anything similar. Any pointers to examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot for the help,
John.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
          TextView tvStatus=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
          TextView tvResult=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);



          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              tvStatus.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
              tvResult.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));

              String a=(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));

                if (a=="1") {
                    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.proceed);  

                    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

                        public void onClick(View view) {                 
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), StoryLine2Part1.class); 
                            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);                              
                        }

                    });
                }

          } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            tvStatus.setText("Press a button to start a scan.");
            tvResult.setText("Scan cancelled.");
          }
        }


      }
    }
```

EDIT:

I have this working (It scans and displays correctly. However I cannot get the check to work since somehow I am not parsing the correct value on the string that I am later on checking in order to proceed. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do exactly that.

Start your activity for result.

```
     try {
            Intent intent = xzingHelper.getScanQrCodeIntent();
            startActivityForResult(intent, XzingHelper.QR_REQ_CODE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText("You need the ZXing 2D BarCode scanner");
            Intent playIntent = xzingHelper.getZxingGooglePlayIntent();
            startActivity(playIntent);
            finish();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == XzingHelper.QR_REQ_CODE){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String qrCodeValue = xzingHelper.getScanResult(data);
                Log.i("Got ZXing result: "+ qrCodeValue);
                dealWithQrCode(qrCodeValue); // Check if the qr code is for the next level
            } else
            if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Cancelled - dont go to next level
                finish();
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Helper class, if they don't have zXing installed it will prompt them:

```
public class XzingHelper {

    public static final int QR_REQ_CODE = 123;

    public Intent getScanQrCodeIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);
        intent.putExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Too dark? Menu > Settings > 'use front light'");
        return intent;
    }

    public Intent getZxingGooglePlayIntent() {
        Uri playUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
        Intent playIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, playUri);
        return playIntent;
    }

    public String getScanResult(Intent data) {
        return data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems logic/interesting. I will work on it with a bit more details through the day and let you know how it went. Thanks a lot for the input however. It's highly appreciated.

Comment: This is roughly correct as an Intent-based integration, but the answer that demonstrates the supplied integration code, IntentIntegrator, is certainly preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the ZXing Library already, but not in the matter of games. You can use it to scan via Intents, what is quite comfortable in my opinion. You can find a description of it in the [ZXing Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent).

Just put all classes from the [intent package](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fandroid-integration%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fintegration%2Fandroid) into your own project. Then you can use whenever you want to start the camera for a user to scan a barcode the following code:

```
// yourActivity will be "this" if you start this from your activity
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity); 
integrator.initiateScan();
```

If you want to limit the code types, that should be scanned, to QR codes you can replace the last line with the following:

```
integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
```

To handle the result you overload the `onActivityResult` method in your activity. This will be called when the scanner returns, and you can unlock your game levels in there:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
   IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
   if (scanResult != null) {
      // a code has been scanned, so handle scan result
   }
}
```

For QR code generation I would just use random string (hash tags from some words), that you can check for in the scan result.